# How do I separate portions of an icon in adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, icon

I have a rasterized icon. As you can see, portions of it are blue. I also have an svg of this same icon but it is a compound shape and those individual pieces are not isolated; it is all black. So if i change the color, it changes the entire icon to that color. Is there an easy way to go about separating those pieces so that I can change the color of only those portions?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to GDSE! It would be easier if you showed us the actual vector shape. Preferably in outline view and with the whole shape selected. If your shape really is a compound path (and not just one path) you should be able to split it using *Object > Compound Path > Release*. If that doesn't work or it splits in the wrong places I'm afraid you have to manually work with the vector paths (or draw the shape from scratch).

Comment: Without knowing how this is constructed it's difficult to say. Have you tried releasing the compound path? Is it made of strokes?  Is it grouped?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not a straight-forward, easy task depending upon proficiency with Illustrator.

Assuming it's all one *shape* and not *strokes*.... The cross lines (blue) would need to be removed, repair the primary helix shape (black), then redraw the cross lines.

---

To be honest, it would probably be easier to simply redraw the shape in Illustrator with strokes, using what you have as a manual tracing guide for the initial curved path.

[image]
<sub>(right-click and open in new window/tab to view larger.)</sub>

...the above is constructed of *only* stroked paths. And all the strokes have *rounded end caps* set.

The initial stroke weights I used for the magenta and cyan strokes, to match the raster image in the question, was 16pts. When the appearance is expanded, the cyan removed, and the fill swapped to a stroke in step 5 above, it leaves a 16pt gap matching the raster image.

If the desire is to prevent stroke scaling, it is possible to `Select All` and then use `Object > Expand` to convert all the strokes to filled shapes. After doing so, the separate shapes comprising the primary helix can be combined to a single shape via Pathfinder or Shape Builder.

---

I noticed I didn't create the *exact* same gaps in the helix that the sample image has. It's easy enough to swap steps - reflect the shape first, and *then* use the scissors to cut pieces and remove them.